# Excel VBA: How do I create a search engine using VBA that takes a cell's row and copies it onto a new tab within the same worksheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make excel focus on the cell that contains what I've searched. So if the cell is out of view in my excel spreadsheet after the search the screen auto adjusts to that specific cell. Then, I need to take everything in that cell's row and have it automatically copy into a new tab within the same excel spreadsheet. But the rows copied in the second tab need to start with Column A in row #5 and continue on. Below is the code I have so far, I'm not too familiar with VBA but I've been working at it. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
`Option Explicit
Sub FindWhat()
Dim sFindWhat As String
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim sh3 As Worksheet
Dim Search As Range
Dim Addr As String
Dim NextRow As Long
Dim cl As Range
Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Set sh3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
'// This will be the row you start pasting data on Sheet3
NextRow = 5
For Each cl In Intersect(sh1.UsedRange, sh1.Columns("A")).Cells
'// the value we're looking for
sFindWhat = cl.Value
'// Find this value in Sheet2:
With sh2.UsedRange
Set Search = .Find(sFindWhat, LookIn:=xlValues,
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
    If Search Is Nothing Then
        '// Get out of here if the value is not found
'// Do NOT Exit the sub, we'll just proceed to next cell in column A
        'Exit Sub
    Else
        '// Make sure next row in Sh3.Column("K") is empty
        While sh3.Range("K" & NextRow).Value <> ""
            NextRow = NextRow + 1
        Wend
        '// Paste the row in column K of sheet 3:
 Search.Resize(1, 12).Copy Destination:=sh3.Range("K" & NextRow)
End If
End With
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: using `Range.Find()` instead of looping through each cell would much more efficient

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim sh3 As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim IdRng As Range
Dim SrcRng As Range
Dim Search As Range
Dim lRow1 As Long
Dim lRow2 As Long
Dim lRow3 As Long

Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plan1")
Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plan2")
Set sh3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plan3")

lRow1 = sh1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
If lRow1 < 4 Then lRow1 = 4
Set IdRng = sh1.Range("A4:A" & lRow1) 'Dynamic ID's Range

lRow2 = sh2.Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
If lRow2 < 4 Then lRow2 = 4
Set SrcRng = sh2.Range("L3:L" & lRow2) 'Dynamic sheet2 search range

For Each rng In IdRng
    Set Search = SrcRng.Find(What:=rng, LookIn:=xlValues)

    If Not Search Is Nothing Then
        lRow3 = sh3.Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If lRow3 < 5 Then lRow3 = 5

        sh2.Range(Search.Address).EntireRow.Copy sh3.Range("K" & lRow3) 'dynamic paste range
    Else
        MsgBox rng & " was not found.", vbInformation, sh1.Name
    End If
Next rng
```

Remember to change `Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plan1")`, `Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plan2")` and `Set sh3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plan3")` to the name of your sheets.

This code has dynamic ranges for your Id's column (sheet1), search's column (sheet2) and paste's column (sheet3), so it will identify automatically in which range the last data is.

Comment: This works great. Thank you very much. However, is there a way for Excel to tell me what cell what I've searched for is in like in the original code? If there isn't it's perfectly fine just wondering.

Comment: @Peergore You're welcome. :) Yes! I re-edited the code, take a look. Just hit this answer up.

Comment: I edited the code as you can now see. So basically vba searches through Sheet2 to see if it has any matching values to Sheet1 in this case the VBA is searching for matching user IDs. Column A of Sheet1 specifically starting at A4 is being compared to Sheet2's Column L specifically starting at L4. Once a match is found the entire row of the matched cell is supposed to be carried over to sheet3 within the range of k5 to v5, k6 to v6, k7 to v7 etc. However, the current code only copies the one cell and not the entire row into the K5 to V5 range. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: hopefully you see this comment

Comment: I changed few things in the code, if you don't undestand something, let me know.